# Geoserver : How to get real rgb bands from geoTIFF

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver, rgba, geotiff

When I go to geoserver -> layer preview -> OpenLayers if I click somewhere on the image it gives me the RGBA bands, how to get these bands with OpenLayers at a specific pixel/coordinate?

I tried using getImageData but it's not accurate (only 0-255) and depends of the level of zoom.

I also tried using getFeatureInfoUrl but I don't know how to use it to get RGBA infos.

Thanks.

Edit : Seems like the suggestion of Mike could work but I have a problem requesting a geotiff image. From this link : [Output formats](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html) it should be possible to request a geotiff or tiff format but on geoserver I only have the choice between png, jpg and gif format, how can I add more formats on geoserver?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this https://eox.at/2018/01/visualizing-geotiff-tiles-with-openlayers/  If you go into the source the key parts are https://data.eox.at/geotiff.js-blog/olgeotiff/olGeoTiff.js which is a custom tile load function to load the tif by xhr and process the data bands and https://data.eox.at/geotiff.js-blog/olgeotiff/plotty.js to convert to display format.

Comment: @Mike : Thanks a lot, I was able to display it but I have a problem with geotiff.browserify, I get this error : 
geotiff.browserify.js:3634 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid byte order value.
I think it is because I request the tif image in png and not in tif but I don't know how to request it in a tif with geoserver, the url I request is this : 
url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts/rest/Foret_sub_crop:T32ULU_20170619T103021__sub_crop/Foret_sub_crop_T32ULU_20170619T103021__sub_crop/EPSG:4326/EPSG:4326:{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}?format=image/png',

Comment: WMTS probably isn't how you want to request GeoTIFF. Use WMS.